# i want to add trigered for active and in active if we have disable and enabled in camera permission

Tags: javascript, permissions, getusermedia, mediastream

```
const webCam = $("#webcam")[0];
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvasImage");
const captureButton = $("#capture-button");

let webcam;
let streamBox;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } })
.then(function (stream) {
  streamBox = stream
    webCam.srcObject = stream;
    $("#messageBox").text('');
    webcam = new Webcam(webCam, "user", canvasElement,null);
    // webcam.start();
    stream.addEventListener("inactive", function (e) {
      $("#messageBox").text('Please allow permission for camera');
  });
    stream.addEventListener("active", function (e) {
      $("#messageBox").text('');
  });
})
.catch(function (error) {
  $("#messageBox").text('Please allow permission for camera');
});
```

please help me active trigered not working and inactive is working

please help me for on trigered

Comment: Can you please provide a Playgroundlink / JSFiddle / Demo to review. As const webCam = $("#webcam")[0], this const is assigned with ID along with index. Need more clarity.